# Constructor vehichle can not applied to the given types?

Tags: java

I have made a class and two child classes which are the Van and the Bicycle, these two classes inherit from Vehicle class, but once I'm running the code I am getting an error ("Constructor vehicle can not applied to the given types ? required (int, String ...)")

```
  //import java.util.*;
 public class Print{
 public static void main (String[]args){
 Vehicle vh = new Vehicle(30,"vauxhall",43434);
 Bicycle b = new Bicycle(6,"yty",6,5);
 //Van v = new Van(6,"yty",6,5,12);
 //System.out.println("check me ");
 //Van v = new Van (50);
 //v.setMaxSpeed(20);
 //v.setStorageCapacity(12);
 //vh.setMaxSpeed(10);
 //b.setMultipleGeers(5);
  }
}
 class Vehicle
 {
   private int maxSpeed;
   private String make;
   private double regNumber; 
  // private int multipleGeers;
  //public Vehicle(){}
  public Vehicle(int maxSpeed, String make,
  double regNumber)
  {
    this.maxSpeed= maxSpeed;
    this.make = make;
    this.regNumber = regNumber;
  }
  public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed){
   if (maxSpeed>0)
    {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
    else{ System.out.println("invalid speed");
    }
  }    
   public  int getMaxSpeed(){         
    return maxSpeed;
   }
    public void setMake(String make){
      this. make=  make;             
   }     
   public  String getMake(){
      return  make;
   }
    public void setRegNumber(double regNumber){
      this.regNumber = regNumber;             
   }   
    public  double getRegNumber(){               
    return regNumber;
   } 
 }

   class Bicycle extends Vehicle
{   
   private int multipleGeers; 
  public Bicycle( int maxSpeed,String make,double 
     regNumber,int multipleGeers)

   {
    super(maxSpeed,make,regNumber);      
    this.multipleGeers = multipleGeers;
   }


    public void setMultipleGeers(int multipleGeers){
       this.multipleGeers = multipleGeers;             
    }
    public int getMultipleGeers(){
        return multipleGeers;
   }
    @Override
     public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed){
     if(maxSpeed <0 && maxSpeed>40){
      System.out.println("value not allowed");
      }
    else{
     super.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed);
       }
   }
     }

    class Van extends Vehicle
   {    
    private int storageCapacity;
   //public Van(){}
   public Van(int maxSpeed, String make, double regNumber,int multipleGeers ,int storageCapacity
)
{
    super(maxSpeed, make, regNumber, multipleGeers);
    //super(maxSpeed,make,regNumber);
    this.storageCapcity = storageCapacity;
}
public void setStorageCapacity(int storageCapacity){
    this.storageCapacity = storageCapacity;             
 } 
public int getStorageCapacity(){
    return storageCapacity;
}
}
```

Comment: The version you posted doesn't even compile with "The constructor Vehicle(int, String, double, int) is  undefined" at `super(maxSpeed, make, regNumber, multipleGeers);`

Answer (score 2):

Your Vehicle constructor is accepting three arguments but, you are trying to supply it four arguments from the class where you extend Vehicle. You have the following:

```
public Vehicle(int maxSpeed, String make, double regNumber) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.make = make;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
    }
```

But you try to invoke it by

```
super(maxSpeed, make, regNumber, multipleGeers);
```

The last argument in the super is the issue. If you remove that then it will become three args and match the super constructor. If you wish to add extra then you need to modify the super Vehicle constructor to include the 4th argument.

Possible solution, change the call to the super constructor as follow:

```
super(maxSpeed, make, regNumber);
```

Or change the s Vehicle constructor to accept one more value as follow:

```
public Vehicle(int maxSpeed, String make, double regNumber, int multipleGeers) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.make = make;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
        //use multipleGeers here 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine , so how should I print it , It is not printing ?

Comment: Great, you also seem to have some typo in **this.storageCapcity = storageCapacity**#

Comment: If this answer helped you then you have the option to mark it as **accepted** as that would help others with similar issue to find the answer that  resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you are passing 3 parameters:

```
  public Vehicle(int maxSpeed, String make,
      double regNumber)
      {
        this.maxSpeed= maxSpeed;
        this.make = make;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
      }
```

While calling the constructor you are passing 4 parameters:

```
super(maxSpeed, make, regNumber, multipleGeers);
```

So consider removing the extra prameter as:

```
super(maxSpeed, make, regNumber);
```